# Duplicate Web client calls with collect list in Spring Boot Web Flux

Tags: spring-boot, arraylist, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am creating a reporting solution where I need to get data from other services in reactive manner using Spring boot WebClient. To save webclient calls in case of list, I used code to create a list from flux using collectlist and then send this list to WebClient API. While API definitly get list and did work. But I see duplicate calls ( exactly count of list ). Which is defeating purpose.

This is function hitting the WebClient Calls

```
public Mono<Map<Long, EmployeeDto>> getEmployee(Flux<ClaimReportDto> claims) {
    log.info("---------------------------------------- Invoked getEmployee");
    Flux<EmployeeDto> employeeDtoFlux =
        claims.switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty())
    .log()
    .map(claim -> claim.getEmployeeId())
    .collectList()
    .flatMapMany(list -> {
                // Web Client Call  
                return employeeClient.findByEmployeeIds(list);
            });
                    
     Mono<Map<Long, EmployeeDto>> employeeDtoMap = employeeDtoFlux
            .collectMap(EmployeeDto::getId, Function.identity());
    return employeeDtoMap;
}
```

Comment: `.switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty())` It doesn't make much sense... from empty to empty. :)

Comment: Looks like something in implementation of employeeClient.findByEmployeeIds(), which performes call per list item